# Find max/min points for multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a question about the general procedures to find the max/min points for multivariable functions, would really help if somebody could please clarify my doubts.

So for single variable function, it's pretty straightforward. We use the FOC to find critical points that satisfy f'(x)=0, and then use SOC to figure out whether it's a max or min by checking the sign of f''(x). i.e if f''(x)>0, the function is concave up, hence a minimum point, or if f''(x)<0, the function is concave down, hence a maximum point.

Now when extending this idea to multivariable functions, we'd still first use the FOC to find all critical points that may or may not be the actual max/min points; but when we subsequently use the SOC, what's to check here now? Do I simply check whether the Hessian of the matrix is positive/negative definite or do I check the sign of every second order derivative of f (Fxx, Fyy, Fxy, Fyx etc etc) at those critical points? Or are these two mechanisms effectively the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is the test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test

Comment: Thanks Rustyn, it's helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the sign is definitely not the way to go.

$$ \left( \begin {matrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end {matrix} \right)$$

is indefinite, although its entries all have the same sign. There are some shortcuts in two dimensions, but in general, you have to know whether the Hessian is definite or not. Given a critical point of a $C^2$ function, that the definiteness of the Hessian is a sufficient condition can be seen by employing the Cauchy form of the Taylor remainder

$$f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) = \underbrace{ \langle \nabla{f}|_{x_0}, h \rangle }_{\text{This term is 0}} + \frac12 \langle H|_{x^*}h, h\rangle$$

where  $H|_{x^*}$ is the Hessian evaluated at a point $x^*$ between $x_0$ and $x_0 + h$. Since $f$ is $C^2$, if the Hessian is definite at $x_0$, it will be definite at $x^*$ also, as long as $h$ is small enough.

Comment: Thanks Eric, that helps. A natural question to follow is that would the definiteness of the Hessian also be a sufficient condition to determine the concavity/convexity of the original function? E.g if the Hessian turns out to be positive definite, which indicates the critical point being a minimum point, would I be able to say the original function is concave up?

Comment: Also could you give me some hints on how to visualize second order derivatives such as dF/dxdy and dF/dydx? Say we set up a function of two independent variables f(x,y) in 3 dimensional space and the function is shaped like a downwards facing paraboloid with a maximum point at (0,0). I tend to visuallize df/dxdx (df/dydy) as the shape of the upward slope along the x(y) axis, but how do I visualize df/dxdy (df/dxdy)? I mean along what directions should I be looking at them? would it be along the direction of the x,y vector? if so, how is the visualization of df/dxdy different from df/dydx? THX!

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "concave up" for a real-valued function of several variables?

Comment: The visualization of $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r \partial s},$$ where $r$ and $s$ are directions (not necessarily just $x$ and $y$ directions) is this: how is the slope of a line through $x_0$ in the $r$ direction changing as we move in the $s$ direction?

Comment: Excuse my inaccurate way of describing concepts, what I meant by "concave up" was that if we have a tangent plane at a point A(x0,y0), then any point defined by the function would be above this tangent plane besides point A.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the visualization explanation, it helps! I'm still trying to build a clear mental image of it, but it's getting closer:)

Comment: It sounds like your definition of "concave up" is equivalent to the definition of $x_0$ being a local minimum. So yes, one does imply the other.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your help!